# How to render a react component x times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component, which should repeat hello x time in a p tag as repeat parameter, I have a problem and nothing is being rendered in the dom, the return of render is empty.

How to fix it?

```
 const content = 'hello';

 const render= (repeat?: number) => {
   const arr = new Array(repeat || 1)
   return arr.map(n => <p key={n}>{content}</p>)
 }

 export const Print = ({ classes, repeat }: Props) => (
   <div>{render(repeat)}</div>
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update:

```
const arr = new Array(repeat || 1);
```

to

```
const arr = new Array(repeat || 1).fill(null);
```

otherwise you'll end up with an [array of empty slots](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhcmmxy/2/). It doesn't have to be `null` btw, just as long as the slots are filled with something before you `map` over the elements. `map` doesn't work on empty slots.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `renderContent` to `render` because the former is not defined.